# Spring JDBC Extensions, Oracle AQ, ClassCastException on listening to queue

Tags: oracle, spring-data, spring-jms

(I hope this below makes sense, I had a bit of a struggle with formatting).

We have an application (currently being refreshed from technology of circa 2005) whose owners require the use of Oracle AQ for message handling.

We are using the Spring JDBC extensions, and when the application begins to listen to the queue it gets a ClassCastException saying "X cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection".

Where X is either a WrappedConnectionJDK7 from jboss when we use a datasource defined in Wildfly e.g.

```
<bean id="dataSource-supsrep" 
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
<property name="username" value="...." />
<property name="password" value="...." />
</bean>
```

or X is a PoolGuardConnectionWrapper from commons.dbcp when we define the datasource like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource-supsrep" 
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
<property name="username" value="...." />
<property name="password" value="...." />
</bean>
```

Message Listener bean is defined like this :

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="xxx.report.dispatch.DispatchMDB" />
```

Message Listener container bean is like this :

```
<bean id="reportProcessorXslfoHigh" 
class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="AQconnectionFactory" />
<property name="destinationName" value="Q1_XSLFO_HIGH" />
<property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
<property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
<property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
<property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="30" />
<property name="idleConsumerLimit" value="1" />
</bean>
```

The connection factory is like this :

```
<orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="AQconnectionFactory"
data-source="dataSource-supsrep" native-jdbc- extractor="oracleNativeJdbcExtractor" />
```

and it uses a Native JDBC Extractor :

```
<bean id="oracleNativeJdbcExtractor" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.support
.nativejdbc.OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor" />
```

---

So my question is - can this be overcome by Spring configuration details - or is there another way round it?  Clearly the underlying connection is needed but after 3 days of research I cannot see how it can be done.

Any clues gratefully received !

Thanks,
    John

Comment: Make sure the class you are using in here class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" is compatible with whatever Oracle wants to cast it to? That would be my first hunch.

Comment: Full stack trace please. It will tell you/us who wants to cast these things, which most likely mostly answers your question.

Comment: @Jens Schauder the Exception is caught somewhere, all I get in the log is a warning such as (sorry can't format it)  2017-07-11 10:38:18,248 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (reportProcessorXslfoHigh-1) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Q1_XSLFO_HIGH' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating the db_connection; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection

Comment: @Kin retrying today with some other datasources found in the Oracle distribution.

Comment: you can format it if you put it in your question.

Comment: even what you posted helps. The exception comes from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java#L877 and you can get the full stacktrace by enabling debug level for logging.

Comment: I think @Kin put me on the right track (or at least one of them as there are so many ways to skin a cat).  After a lot of faffing about with different things I found a datasource definition that works '<bean id="dataSource-supsrep" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
<property name="user" value="..." /> 
<property name="password" value="..."/> 
</bean> '   I had tried it before but was fooled - it said "url" was not allowed - "URL" is however !  - Thanks Gents!